# Proof of Zero Knowledge Groth16

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs

I understand that in the  non-interactive linear  form (page 15 of Groth16: https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/260.pdf), given $A$ and $B$ in the proof $(A,B,C)$,
the simulator can compute the $C$ by:
$C =\frac{AB-\alpha\beta-D}{\delta} $ where $D = \sum^{l}_{i=0} {a_i(\beta u_i(x) + \alpha v_i(x) + w_i(x))} $.

However, I don't get how the simulator would work when the scheme is compiled to SNARK.Here, when all keys are raised to power form, we have: $e(A,B) = e(C, g^\delta) e(g^\alpha, g^\beta) e(D, g)$.
I see that $e(C, g^\delta) = e(A,B)/(e(g^\alpha, g^\beta) e(D, g))$, but how could the simulator extract the $G_1$ element $C$ from the $G_t$ element $e(C, g^\delta)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simulator would not generate random elements of $\mathbb G_T$, but would as before generate uniform random values $A,B\in\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ and compute $C$ per your equation. They would then SNARK-ify these numbers by $[A]=g^A\in\mathbb G_1$, $[B]=h^B\in\mathbb G_2$ and $[C]=g^C\in\mathbb G_1$ per the bottom of page 6 (note that these SNARK-ified elements are all uniformly distributed in their respective groups).

The equation $e([A],[B])=e([C],h^\delta) e(g^\alpha,h^\beta)e(g,h)^D$ would then automatically be true by the bilinearity property of $e$.

Comment: Many thanks for the response. What's intriguing to me is that: why would one allow the simulator to know the trap door (the toxic values such as the $\delta$ - shouldn't they be "forgotten" by the set up process)? In another word, why would the scheme allow the simulator to be "super-power" like a set-up?

Comment: I don't think of values such as $\delta$ as "toxic" values; they're provided to verifiers as part of $\mathbf\sigma$ and I think of verifier information as public.

Comment: But on page 17 0f Groth16 (https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/260.pdf), the trapdoor $\tau$ is defined as $\tau = (\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta, x)$. The verifier key $\sigma$ is raised to power in group $G_1$ and $G_2$. I don't think the $\delta$ is visible to verifier (i.e., the verifier can only see $g^\delta$), if I'm understanding it right.

Comment: Apologies, you are correct. Providing the simulator with $\tau$ is part of the defined rules of section 2.2; I would interpret this as the simulator being able to come up with the exact same proof if exactly the same blinding values were chosen at random.

Comment: Thanks again for clarification!